# Swift array always give me "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I am having a problem with array in Swift, I want to make an array like this :

```
var Test : [[String]] = [[]]
let test_string = "HELLO"

   for var i = 0; i <= 15; ++i {
      for x in test_string.characters {
         Test[i].append("\(i)\(x)")
      }
   }

print(Test[1][1]) // This should print 1E
```

but this always gives me this error ! :

```
fatal error: Array index out of range
```

What I am missing here ?

Comment: You're missing to append anything to `Test`, There is no `Test[0]` when executing `Test[i].append("\(i)\(x)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array of arrays is empty, so there is no `Test[0]` (technically you initialize it to `[[]]` which means it has one element, so `Test[0]` does exist, but then `Test[1]` doesn't, which is confusing). You need to initialize each element to an empty array:

```
var Test : [[String]] = [] // This really should be an empty array for consistency.
let test_string = "HELLO"

   for var i = 0; i <= 15; ++i {
      Test.append([]) // <== initialize the array
      for x in test_string.characters {
         Test[i].append("\(i)\(x)")
      }
   }

print(Test[1][1]) // This should print 1E
```

This isn't very good Swift, though. C-style `for` loops are deprecated (also, variables should always be camelCase, never leading caps or using underscores).

This can be translated nicely into a nested mapping:

```
let testString = "HELLO"
let indexedCharacters = (0..<15).map { i in
    testString.characters.map { c in "\(i)\(c)" }
}
```

This maps the numbers 0-15 into arrays of strings based on the characters. Once you understand the basics of `map`, this should be much easier to comprehend than the original loop. (I'm not saying that `map` is better than `for` in general. Often a simple `for-in` loop is best. But for such a simple mapping, `map` is very clear and uses Swift's features nicely.)

Comment: Fixed; it's `append()`. This is not good Swift, though. I'm thinking about how to improve it.

Comment: yes now working :) .. but why its not good swift , in terms of what , can you explain to me please i am new to swift :)

Comment: Also, array names should be plural. Although I am not sure what they should be when they are nested. Good answer.

Comment: @Caleb Agreed. Tried to pick a better name, though I'm not sure what this array would ever be used for, so I'm not sure that's the best name either. :D

Comment: yes most of the time i use lower case but from now on it will be always lol.. thanks for your explanation :) ,