# how to Reload data on table view without crashing in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift3, wait

I have a TableView in my app that when user tap the button in one of the cells the safari will open in the app and when the safari dismiss the app will crash because I want to update one of the parameters in the tableview so I need to remove all and append them again from Json But this will take some seconds so the app will crash because there is no data to show I used Timer But timer is not good solution because some times it will take more time than timer so it will crash again I need a method that wait to finish and then do some thing else of if you think this is not a good solution too please guide me which solution is good for this problem

here is what I used in my app after dismiss safari in application(its not all of the codes but these codes has problems )

```
 if let payed = dict.value(forKey: "payed"){

                            factorViewController.payed.removeAll()
                            self.factorTableView.reloadData()
                            factorViewController.payed.append(payed as! Int)
                            self.factorTableView.reloadData()

                            print("payed = \([payed])")

                        }
```

Comment: What is the crash report?

Comment: index out of range because when I remove data in factorViewController.payed there is no information to show

Comment: add cellforrow and numberofrows method

Comment: No you didn't read my question completely I added these method easily and the app will work without Updating information the problem is that I want to update information in my table view

Comment: I mean add your `cellforrow` and `numberofrows ` here in your question, so that i can check what you done. Why you added timer for reload tableview??

Comment: I didn't import all of my codes here But number of rows is not payed.count it is factorTitle.count

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I know how to use tableview! the problem for me is updating information thats it! without updating information I don't have any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok That was easier than I thought ! I just defined another variables in my app and when started getting Json append new data to the new variables and then equals new variables to old variables ! thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading the data only once:

```
 if let payed = dict.value(forKey: "payed") {
     // Empty Array here
     factorViewController.payed.removeAll()
     // You are appending here, so array will not be empty
     factorViewController.payed.append(payed as! Int)
     // Now you can reload data
     self.factorTableView.reloadData() 
     print("payed = \([payed])")
     // Also, if this doesn't work, you can use a callback(completion handler).
 }
```

That way, your array will not be empty when you need to reload data

Comment: `numberOFRows` returns array.count and now i empty my array and reload tableview. Do you think it crashes with `IndexOutOfBound` ??

Comment: if that is the case, you need to use a callback. Can you please show us where you are accessing the array?

Comment: factorViewController.title.count this will count number of rows not payed

Comment: Doesnt matter is never crashed and dont need to use callback when your are in same VC. If count is zero then number of rows does not call, so your answer does not make sense.

Comment: But It will crash again with this answer

Comment: can I use delay for dismiss safari?

Answer (score 0):

**How TableView Works**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return your_array.count // It returns how much cells you want in your tableview.
    }

 // This func defines what you wanted in your cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = dequeue_property // to dequeue your cell
     your_lbl.text = your_array[indexpath.row] // as per logic
    return cell
}
```

**In your case**

Count of array in `numberOfRowsInSection` is more than the array you'r using in the `cellForRowAt` so on dequeue your cell have more index than the array you are using in `cellForRow`. Thats why is doesn't getting index and crashes with `IndexOutOFRange`

You have array issue not tableView Reload issue

**Take ref :** [Swift array always give me "fatal error: Array index out of range"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604558/swift-array-always-give-me-fatal-error-array-index-out-of-range)

Comment: I know how to use tableview ! I just want to use waiting method for information in tableview just this

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi You not getting what exactly i am saying

Comment: you mean I have to remove all data in the cells and then reload all of them?